# Insert map entry by r-value moving of mapped_type

Tags: c++, dictionary, move-semantics

I have a map with a (fairly) simple key-type and a complex mapped-type, like so:

```
map<string, vector<string>> myMap;
```

If I have a `vector<string>` in hand, is it possible to insert an entry into the map which copies the key but moves the mapped-value? That is, is there some way to do:

```
string key = "Key";
vector<string> mapped;
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
  mapped.push_back("Some dynamic string");

// Insert by moving mapped; I know I'm done with it
myMap.insert(make_pair(key, move(mapped))); // This seems to move key too
```

Comment: The question is, where are you going to move your mapped type to?  It won't exist in the map unless you have previously created it there.

Comment: Just use pointer as map value maybe easier?

Comment: @TonyTheLion - `vector` has a move-constructor, right? I'd like the `pair<string, vector>` in the map to have its vector part constructed by move.

Comment: @billz - what, and cope with the memory alloc-dealloc manually? No thanks. I'll be referring to `myMap` long after `mapped` is out of scope.

Comment: `map<string,unique_ptr<vector<string>>> myMap`, you don't need to alloc-dealloc manually

Comment: @billz: You'll get exactly the same issue moving `unique_ptr` into the map as you would `vector`; all you've gained is an extra layer of complication.

Comment: @MikeSeymour however he would be sure the element will never be copied but moved, because unique_ptr does not allow copying. A move-only vector would be great to avoid accidental copies in this case.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace):

```
myMap.emplace(key, move(mapped));
```

this calls the appropiate `std::pair` constructor in-place:

```
template< class U1, class U2 >
pair( U1&& x, U2&& y );
```

Since the first argument is an l-value, the key gets copied, but the second (mapped) is an rvalue and thus gets move-constructed.