# Moving an object into a map

Tags: c++, c++11

The problem with this is that the huge objects will be copied into the maps

```
Huge huge1(some,args);
Huge huge2(some,args);

std::map<int,Huge> map1;
std::map<Huge,int> map2;

map1.insert({0,huge1});
map2.insert({huge2,0});
```

how can I guarantee a move? Will this work or is there more to it?

```
map1.insert({0,std::move(huge1)});
map2.insert({std::move(huge2),0});
```

Comment: I asked exactly this a few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581414/insert-map-entry-by-r-value-moving-of-mapped-type

Comment: Not quite the same thing, @Chowlett.

Comment: @Yakk - ...because the key-type is also available for move, where I needed to ensure it was copied? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @Chowlett yep -- you wanted partial move, while the OP just wants to move.  Admittedly, your question answers OP's question.  :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`std::map::insert` has an overload for R-values:

`std::pair<iterator,bool> insert(value_type&&);`

Any expression which binds to this overload will invoke R-value constructors.  Since `std::map<K,V>::value_type` is `std::pair<const key_type, mapped_type>`, and `std::pair` has a constructor that takes R-values:

```
template<class U1, class U2> 
pair(U1&& x, U2&& y);
```

then you are guaranteed that R-value constructors for `key_type` and `mapped_type` will be invoked, both in the creation of the `pair` object, and in the map insertion, as long as you insert the pair using an expression that creates R-values, such as:

```
map1.insert(std::make_pair(0, Huge());
```

OR

```
map1.insert(std::make_pair(0, std::move(huge1));
```

Of course, all of this is dependent on `Huge` having a proper R-value constructor:

```
Huge(Huge&& h)
{
  ...
}
```

Finally, you can also use `std::map::emplace` if you simply want to construct a new `Huge` object as an element in the map.

Comment: I would also add that the example he uses with brace initializer also works.  Also, the pair constructor is actually a universal-reference constructor, in that all/either/none of the arguments may be r-value and it will still be chosen.  Calling it an r-value constructor may confuse people to think both arguments must be r-value, which is not true.

Answer (score 16):

You could do that (the `{0,std::move(huge1)}` part). But you could also skip the middleman (assuming you're constructing the objects within the function) like this:

```
map1.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 0, std::forward_as_tuple(some, args));
map2.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(some, args), 0);
```

Or, if your function is given the objects, you can still use `emplace`:

```
map1.emplace(0, std::move(huge1));
map2.emplace(std::move(huge1), 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative that avoids both copying and moving would be to use [`std::map::emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace). From the linked reference page:

> Inserts a new element to the container. **The element is constructed in-place, i.e. no copy or move operations are performed.** The constructor of the element type (value_type, that is, std::pair) is called with exactly the same arguments as supplied to the function, forwarded with std::forward(args)....

Answer (score 2):

Along with the above, you can also rely on `std::unique_ptr<>`'s lack of a copy constructor, though this changes the interface slightly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class Huge {
 public:
  Huge(int i) : x{i} {}
  int x;
};

using HugePtrT = std::unique_ptr<Huge>;
using MyMapT = std::map<int, HugePtrT>;


int
main() {
  MyMapT myMap;
  myMap[42].reset(new Huge{1});
  std::cout << myMap[42]->x << std::endl;
  myMap[43] = std::move(myMap[42]);
  if (myMap[42])
    std::cout << "42: " << myMap[42]->x << std::endl;
  if (myMap[43])
    std::cout << "43: " << myMap[43]->x << std::endl;
}
```

which produces the expected output:

```
1
43: 1
```

If you omit the `std::move()` call, the program will fail to compile. Similarly, you could use `.reset()` to assign the pointer.

This has the advantage that it will work on classes that don't have an R-value constructor, is very light weight, memory ownership is clearly defined, and gives you a `boost::optional<>`-like semantics. An argument could be made that `std::unique_ptr` is lighter weight than an object that has been moved via an R-value constructor because an R-Value moved object requires an allocation (though to be fair, all of the C++11 compilers that I'm aware of support Return Value Optimizations or copy elision), even though the guts of the object are moved.

The reason `std::unique_ptr<>` works like this is because `std::unique_ptr<>` does not have a copy constructor, it only has a move constructor.